# i am change expo version from 48 to 49 and facing error in expo dashboard while build apk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

enter image description here  `"expo": "49", "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0", "expo-updates": "~0.18.19",`

Please give help me,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolve it

if anyone facing issue same like me
so please check your expo dashboard error log
and try to find library name
and install library

in my case i have install

```
"expo-modules-autolinking": "1.2.0",
```